# seasonal_decompose: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes on a series

Tags: pandas, numpy, time-series, statsmodels, decomposition

I know there are many questions on this topic, but none of them helped me to solve this problem. I'm really stuck on this.

With a simple series:

```
0
2016-01-31  266
2016-02-29  235
2016-03-31  347
2016-04-30  514
2016-05-31  374
2016-06-30  250
2016-07-31  441
2016-08-31  422
2016-09-30  323
2016-10-31  168
2016-11-30  496
2016-12-31  303

import statsmodels.api as sm
logdf = np.log(df[0])
decompose = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(logdf,freq=12, model='additive')
decomplot = decompose.plot()
```

i keep getting: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,) (14,)`

I've tried pretty much everything, passing only logdf.values, passing a non-log series. It doesn't work.
Numpy and statsmodel versions:

```
print(statsmodels.__version__)
print(pd.__version__)
print(np.__version__)
0.6.1
0.18.1
1.11.3
```

Comment: What is the zero in front of your data series? Also, we cannot estimate a seasonal effect if there is only one season. There is no way to distinguish season from trend or other effects.

Comment: The 0 above the dates I think just means he has a pandas Series, indexed on those dates.

Comment: Max is right, pandas series indexed on those dates. Why we cannot estimate a seasonal.effect with only one season? Anyway is just a sample series, i got a larger dataset grouped by dates (actually resampled), and still i got this error (should be numpy related i guess)

Comment: Did you ever found out the issue with this? I'm running against this very annoying error too.

Comment: Same problem here too

Comment: I think freq parameter should be smaller than the time series length. It's not the version problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @yoonforh pointed, in my case this was fixed by setting the `freq` parameter to less than the time series length. E.g. if your time series `ts` looks like this:

```
2014-01-01    0.0
2014-02-01    0.0
2014-03-01    1.0
2014-04-01    1.0
2014-05-01    0.0
2014-06-01    1.0
2014-07-01    1.0
2014-08-01    0.0
2014-09-01    0.0
2014-10-01    1.0
2014-11-01    0.0
2014-12-01    0.0
```

the shape is

```
(12,)
```

so this will give the error as per above:

```
seasonal_decompose(ts, freq=12, model='additive')
```

but if I try `freq=11` or any other `int` less than 12, e.g.

```
seasonal_decompose(ts, freq=11, model='additive')
```

this works

Answer (score 0):

i noticed that with newer pandas and statsmodel versions it seems to work.

Given a series:

```
2016-01-03    8.326275
2016-01-10    8.898229
2016-01-17    8.754792
2016-01-24    8.658172
2016-01-31    8.731659
2016-02-07    9.047233
2016-02-14    8.799662
2016-02-21    8.783549
2016-02-28    8.782783
2016-03-06    9.081825
2016-03-13    8.737934
2016-03-20    8.658693
2016-03-27    8.666475
2016-04-03    9.029178
2016-04-10    8.781555
2016-04-17    8.720787
2016-04-24    8.633909
2016-05-01    8.937744
2016-05-08    8.804925
2016-05-15    8.766862
2016-05-22    8.651899
2016-05-29    8.653645
...
```

And pd/sm version:

```
statsmodels.__version__ 0.8.0
pandas.__version__ 0.20.1
```

This is the result:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
logdf = np.log(df_series)
decompose = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(logdf, model='additive', filt=None, freq=1, two_sided=True)
decompose.plot()
```

[image]

I hope this could solve your problem too.

Comment: doesn't setting `freq=1` undermines the sense of decomposition? If I understand correctly, seasional and residual components will always be empty